# Given a sequence $[s_n]$, construct a matrix $A$ such that for fixed $i, j$ of your choosing, $A^n_{i, j}$ is $s_n$ for all $n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this possible / is there a known construction?

I'll restate the question.  I have finite (or infinite if you want to try) sequence $s_1, s_2...s_n$.  I want to construct a matrix $A$, such for for some fixed $i, j$ of your choice (whatever works best), the $i, jth$ entry of $A^n$ is $s_n$ for all $n$.

In other words, I want to create a matrix that "generates" a given sequence in some particular fixed entry of the power sequence of that matrix.

It doesn't matter what happens in the rest of the matrix.  Just choose any fixed $i, j$ and I only care about what happens in $A^n_{i, j}$

Comment: Means that $A^n_{i,j}=s_n$ for all $i,j$? Or how does the entry of the matrix is affected by the sequence?

Comment: Not for all i, j.  Just for any particular i, j of your choosing.  The rest of the matrix can be anything.  I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: The map $A \mapsto A^n$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial in the entries of $A$, which puts constraints on the sequence $s_n$. For example, if $s_n$ grows super-exponentially there will be no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example: $s$ is the sequence $4, 6, 2, 3, 6$.
Build the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{
     0&   1  &     0&     0  &   0&     4\\
     0&   0  &     1&    0  &   0&     6\\
     0&   0  &     0&     1  &   0&     2\\
     0  &   0&     0&    0   &  1  &   3\\
     0  &   0&     0&     0 &    0 &    6\\
     0  &   0&     0&     0&     0 &    0
}
$$
Then the upper right entry of this matrix and its powers (up to the 5th power) will be $4, 6, 2, 3, 6$, in that order. This can clearly be generalized to any (finite) length sequence.

It works because the "just above the diagonal" entries work to shift each row of the matrix up by one unit at each step, moving the numbers from your sequence into the desired position.

I think that with substantial fiddling, you *might* even get a sequence of length $6$ to appear using a $6 \times 6$ matrix, but I don't have the energy to make that happen right now.

Comment: Yeah this appears to work.  I would be curious to see if it can be done with one fewer dimension, but it'd be much harder probably.

Comment: If you put a "1" in the lower left corner, it messes up $A^2$ in the upper-right entry...but you can fix that by adjusting the $(2,6)$ entry. And then you have to adjust the $(3, 6)$ entry, and so on. And when you're all done, you end up with *something* in the $(1,6)$ entry of $A^6$ that may not be what you wanted. But then the choice to put $1$ in that bottom entry was arbitrary...you could try $2$, or $17$ or...you could work out a general formula for the $(1.6)$ entry of $A^6$ as a function of the number $b$ you put in the $(6,6)$ slot at first. I don't have the energy. :(